# FTP Connection over sockets in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, ftp

It's possible to connect to a FTP server with sockets in windows phone? If yes how can I implement it?

How do I provide the login and the password to the server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

In Windows Phone 7 (before Mango update) there were no sockets. In Mango update you can create an FTP client, yes. Note: it will always work in Passive mode. As for how you provide credentials - this is defined in RFC 959 (FTP protocol).

Unless you have good experience with sockets, I recommend using third-party component. Our [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-ftps.php) includes FTP/FTPS component for Windows Phone 7 and /n software has FTP client in their IPWorks for WP7 product.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want to buy a third-party component. So this is not a solution.

Comment: Then your only solution is to implement an FTP client. Good luck!